# Adding JavaScript File to Angular 4 Component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

Let's just say I make a custom JavaScript file ie 'custom.js'

How would I implement this into a Component?

If I add 'custom.js' to index.html, that's fine but is there any way I can add it specifically to the component?

Comment: what would this file have?

Comment: animation, ect. For example, moving around a navigation bar, ect

Comment: Can't you just `import` from inside your component definition? Although, I guess that would require it to be a module. Is it possible to change your custom.js into a module?

Comment: Can you show how your .js looks like and where you have kept it in your project?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Step: 1**=> Create and write your js code say "*synapse.js*" in */app* folder. The function or constant which you to use in a component should be exported using `export` keyword. *for ex*:

*synapse.js*

```
export function synapseThrow() {
  return 'hello'
}

export const MY_VAR = 'world!';
```

**Step: 2**=> in *angular-cli.json*, add the below part in `apps` object.

```
"scripts": ["app/synapse.js"]
```

**Step: 3**=> in *tsconfig.json*, add the below property in `compilerOptions`.

```
"allowJs": true
```

**Step: 4**=> in any component say in "*app.component.ts*" import the "*synapse.js*" file using `import` keyword.

*app.component.ts*

```
// other imports

import { MY_VAR, synapseThrow } from './synapse';

// other app code here

ngOnInit(){
  const returned = MY_VAR;
  const returnFunc = synapseThrow();
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way:

- Put js file in path: assets/js/custom.js
- Code your component

ts file

```
export class MyComponent implements AfterViewChecked {
  constructor(private elementRef: ElementRef) {

  }
  ngAfterViewChecked() {
    var s = document.createElement("script");
    s.type = "text/javascript";
    s.src = "../assets/js/custom.js";
    this.elementRef.nativeElement.appendChild(s);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring a variable that you have inside of your custom.js file

---

```
declare var aFunction: any;

import '../../../js/custom.js';

export class ExampleComponent{

    variable: any;

    constructor() { }

    ngOnInit() { 
       new aFunction(this.variable);  //aFunction() is inside custom.js
    }
}
```